# Capture dynamic values from the various response

Tags: jmeter

HTTP request body in JMeter

{"guid":"**3659174697251947**","syncId":"${C_SyncID1}:8:9474","changes":{"_CreatedDate":{"value":1674476500333},"IsDeleted":{"value":false},"CheckinQuantityEdit":{"value":"0"},"OrderQuantity":{"value":"1"},"LineStatus":{"value":"Purchaseorder"},"CheckinPrice":{"value":"65.62"},"ProductName":{"value":null},"LineNumber":{"value":"1"},"RequiresMobileSync":{"value":true},"CheckInQuantity":{"value":"1"},"NativeMobile.OrderItem_DynamicCustomerProduct":{"value":null},"NativeMobile.OrderItem_Order":{"value":"**26177172834105120**"},"NativeMobile.OrderItem_CustomerProduct":{"value":"**28710447624499413**"},"isDeletedOnMobileDevice":{"value":false},"ProductCode":{"value":null}}},

for the above request we need to capture - NativeMobile.OrderItem_Order":{"value":"**26177172834105120** and -- guid":"**3659174697251947**", for the product NativeMobile.OrderItem_CustomerProduct":{"value":"**28710447624499413**"},

Response 1
from the  below response we need to capture order guid **26177172834105120** based on OrderNumber":{"value":"**J40000099VN0001**"}

So if the OrderNumber":{"value":"**J40000099VAN0001**"  guid will be guid":"**26177172834105120**"

"OrderNumber":{"value":"**J40000099VAN0001**"},"JobNumber":{"value":"jbdemo"},"FulfilmentMethod":{"value":"Collection"},"DeliveryAttended":{"value":null},"OrderAPI":{"value":"ICON"},"CustomerOrderTypeAtSubmission":{"readonly":true,"value":"JobOrder"},"OrderDateSubmitted":{"value":1674476500321},"SubOrderType":{"value":null},"NativeMobile.Order_OrderingEntity":{"value":"31806672368314430"},"ICONAPIStatus":{"value":null},"OrderPostStatus":{"value":"Success"},"isDeletedOnMobileDevice":{"value":false},"OrderNumberInteger":{"value":"99"}},"guid":"**26177172834105120**","hash":"kxniswgHZITElfZ5lHihQiGnuLsuLM4e407HOTy8ih0=","

Response 2

If NativeMobile.OrderItem_Order":{"value":"**26177172834105120**" and
NativeMobile.OrderItem_CustomerProduct":{"value":"**28710447624499413**"}

Then only guid will be guid":"**3659174697251947**"

{"changes":{},"commits":[],"committedObjectsOmitted":false,"deletes":[],"hasMoreItems":false,"newpersistable":[],"objects":[{"attributes":
{"ProductCode":{"value":null},"NativeMobile.OrderItem_Order":{"value":"**26177172834105120**"},"NativeMobile.OrderItem_DynamicCustomerProduct":{"value":null},"RequiresMobileSync":{"value":false},"AmountMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":"0"},"CheckInQuantity":{"value":"1"},"LineNumber":{"value":"2"},"CheckinPrice":{"value":"91.55"},"LineStatus":{"value":"Purchaseorder"},"ProductName":{"value":null},"isDeletedOnMobileDevice":{"value":false},"OrderQuantity":{"value":"1"},"CheckinQuantityEdit":{"value":"0"},"NativeMobile.OrderItem_CustomerProduct":{"value":"**28710447624499413**"},"IsDeleted":{"value":false},"_CreatedDate":{"value":1674476500342},"FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"**3659174697251947**","hash":"Brd19q5Z1yYq0L8U1noeIsvcthz89N/pvTg/5EqeBnY="

Please help me out her to capture the values **3659174697251947** and **26177172834105120**

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `guid` for the `NativeMobile.OrderItem_CustomerProduct==28710447624499413` using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), the relevant [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) query will be:

```
$.[?(@.changes.['NativeMobile.OrderItem_CustomerProduct'].value == '28710447624499413')].guid
```

[image]

Pretty much similar you can get the `NativeMobile.OrderItem_Order`

```
$.changes[?(@.['NativeMobile.OrderItem_CustomerProduct'].value == '28710447624499413')].['NativeMobile.OrderItem_Order'].value
```

[image]

With regards to responses 1 and 2 - I cannot help you because your JSON is incomplete.

More information:

- [JSONPath Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators)
- [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)