# Capture values using JSON extractor with multiple combination values rules

Tags: jmeter

1. from below response we need to capture

if OrderNumber":{"value":"J-40-000093-VAN0001"} we need capture guid":"26177172834105110*

{"changes":{},"commits":[],"committedObjectsOmitted":false,"deletes":[],"hasMoreItems":false,"newpersistable":[],"objects":[{"attributes":{"_ShowSites":{"value":false},"ICONStatusTime":{"readonly":true,"value":1674457196799},"DeliveryDate":{"value":null},"NativeMobile.Order_DeliveryAddress":{"value":null},"NativeMobile.Order_CustomFlowItems_Temp":{"value":null},"Status":{"value":"Complete"},"RequiredByDate":{"value":1674529200000},"CollectionASAP":{"value":true},"TotalPriceAtOrderSubmission":{"value":"122.42"},"NativeMobile.Order_Checkout_JobOrder":{"value":"68116944363989153"},"DropToCommunalArea":{"value":false},"CustomerReference":{"value":"testing1"},"OrderType":{"value":"JobOrder"},"DeliveryAccessRestricted":{"value":false},"NativeMobile.Order_SGBranch":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"APIAttemptsCount":{"readonly":true,"value":"1"},"Address":{"value":null},"OrderEmailStatus":{"value":"Success"},"_CreatedDate":{"value":1674456764925},"HasAtLeastOneItem":{"value":true},"NativeMobile.Order_UserAccount_Operative":{"value":"66991044457146029"},"CheckInDate":{"value":1674457678401},"NativeMobile.Order_Job_WiderOrder":{"value":null},"RequiresMobileSync":{"value":false},"ICONOrderStatus":{"readonly":true,"value":"Pending"},"TotalOrderPriceAtCheckIn":{"value":"122.42"},"OrderNumber":{"value":"J-40-000093-VAN0001"},"JobNumber":{"value":"jbdemo"},"FulfilmentMethod":{"value":"Collection"},"DeliveryAttended":{"value":null},"OrderAPI":{"value":"ICON"},"CustomerOrderTypeAtSubmission":{"readonly":true,"value":"JobOrder"},"OrderDateSubmitted":{"value":1674456764928},"SubOrderType":{"value":null},"NativeMobile.Order_OrderingEntity":{"value":"31806672368314430"},"ICONAPIStatus":{"value":null},"OrderPostStatus":{"value":"Success"},"isDeletedOnMobileDevice":{"value":false},"OrderNumberInteger":{"value":"93"}},"guid":"26177172834105110","hash":"fh+MfPCaDRjTn9gjdva5Qx5uxU+6lBjGDcmIpFWJ0OY=","objectType":"NativeMobile.Order"},

2. from below response

if  NativeMobile.OrderItem_Order":{"value":"26177172834105120"} and NativeMobile.OrderItem_CustomerProduct":{"value":"28710447624498114"}   we need to capture guid":"3659174697251949

{"changes":{},"commits":[],"committedObjectsOmitted":false,"deletes":[],"hasMoreItems":false,"newpersistable":[],"objects":[{"attributes":{"ProductCode":{"value":null},"NativeMobile.OrderItem_Order":{"value":"26177172834105120"},"NativeMobile.OrderItem_DynamicCustomerProduct":{"value":null},"RequiresMobileSync":{"value":false},"AmountMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":"0"},"CheckInQuantity":{"value":"1"},"LineNumber":{"value":"4"},"CheckinPrice":{"value":"1"},"LineStatus":{"value":"Pick note printed"},"ProductName":{"value":null},"isDeletedOnMobileDevice":{"value":false},"OrderQuantity":{"value":"1"},"CheckinQuantityEdit":{"value":"0"},"NativeMobile.OrderItem_CustomerProduct":{"value":"28710447624498114"},"IsDeleted":{"value":false},"_CreatedDate":{"value":1674476500360},"FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251949","hash":"pzZHRHrMSglxWv+E8I+/1JFXiztj1NRykkEe3mWUhvM=","objectType":"NativeMobile.OrderItem"}

Please help me to capture the guids

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't that you who asked an identical twin of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75230250/capture-dynamic-values-from-the-various-response/75230433#75230433)? The solution would be exactly the same:

Take a look at [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor), the relevant [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries would be:

1. `$.objects[?(@.attributes.OrderNumber.value == 'J-40-000093-VAN0001')].guid`

   [image]
2. `$.objects[?(@.attributes.['NativeMobile.OrderItem_Order'].value == '26177172834105120' && @.attributes.['NativeMobile.OrderItem_CustomerProduct'].value=='28710447624498114')].guid`

   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me get the values, here one more value i am trying to capture  from second 2nd response                                                                                    
_CreatedDate":{"value":1674476500360}

Comment: but when I try using expression                                                                                             $.objects[?(@.attributes.['NativeMobile.OrderItem_Order'].value == '26177172834105120' && @.attributes.['NativeMobile.OrderItem_CustomerProduct'].value=='28710447624498114')].['_CreatedDate'].value            promting no match. please help